# How to resolve Network Error retry again error on Ubuntu one login?

Tags: login, ubuntu-touch, launchpad

When I am trying to install apps from Ubuntu App Store on my nexus 5 Ubuntu 15.04 r92 I can't login to app store it always gives the same error. My credentials and network settings are right (I am asking this question on my nexus ubuntu and logged into this site via launchpad id.).

Comment: Did you try to disable Wi-Fi and reenable it? Sometimes this helps for me if I run in connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using the phone in? If it's not English, set it to English and then try installing the apps after restarting. That worked like a charm for me. I personally use English (Denmark) so that I can use my device in the 24 hour format, but I believe most flavours of English would work for this purpose. You can revert it back to your preferred language later on and restart to make that change permanent.

Don't forget Ubuntu Touch is still a fairly young and therefore buggy operating system, and the bugs related to specific languages (such as the horrid bug with Turkish) take longer to be solved since they only matter to a narrow spectrum of users.